# Can one include separate files in htaccess for a list of redirects?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, include

My main htaccess file does a bunch of things for my site to function correctly.
I have added redirects for pages that have moved. I don't have root access to the server and using .htaccess is my only option.

Is it possible to include separate files for the redirects in the .htaccess file so I can keep them separate and write programatically to the additional files that hold my redirects?

Basically I want to reference separate files from my .htaccess to manage rules dynamically and also neaten up one long .htaccess file with a few smaller files.

I also want to add redirect rules on the fly as things change on the site within my application.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a RewriteMap http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/rewrite/rewritemap.html

Let's say your map file looks like this and is called moved.map:-

```
/about                               profile
/page/that/has/moved                 new/location
```

You .htaccess would need something like this:-

```
RewriteMap moved                     txt:moved.map
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}           ^(.*)$
RewriteCond ${moved:%1|NOT_PRESENT}  !NOT_PRESENT [NC]
RewriteRule .?                       ${moved:%1} [NC,R=301]
```

This will redirect with a 301 status code http://your.domain.com/about to http://your.domain.com/profile and redirect http://your.domain.com/page/that/has/moved to http://your.domain.com/new/location

You can then programmatically create moved.map.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, but this advice no use to anyone using `.htaccess` files for their redirection as the OP discusses in the question.

Comment: How does it not help someone redirect from an htaccess file? The rules are in the htaccess file. Just the URLS themselves are in a separate file. Those were the requirements.

Comment: Because you can only use maps in a server or vhost context.

Comment: Where does he say that is an issue?

Comment: Baynez, you (should) know that Apache best practice is to avoid using `.htaccess` files _if_ you have update access to the system or a vhost config.  If you look across the 100s of rewrite Qs that I have, then you will see that very few -- the odd 1 or 2 -- use .htaccess files when they have such access, so it make no sense to give advice that is misleading in 98% of cases without first checking.

Comment: I don't have root access to the server and using .htaccess is my only option - I have updated the question to include this. Apache best practice is also not a consideration when redirects must be used to tell search engines that pages have moved permanently unless the redirect is done another way. Even with root access, adding redirects to a vhost config is cumbersome for SEO purposes when numerous redirects are required. For this example I am really wanting to dynamically create rules which is also not possible with vhosts.

Comment: If I had root access however, this would be the ideal solution.

Comment: @Innate are you saying that the solution above does not work for you?

Comment: Ironically, the link to apache.org is 404

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `.htaccess` files then don't bother with **RewriteMap** -- it only applies if you have root access to the server or vhost config, which is never the case when you purchase a shared service offering.

If you are constrained to use `.htaccess` files then you have two options:

- The first is to do what some packages do and that is to get your application to rewrite the `.htaccess` file based on a rewrite map that you maintain within in it.  The best way to do this is to have "bookends" in your .htaccess file e.g.

  ```
  ##++AUTOMATIC rewrite rules
  <rules inserted by your app>
  ##--AUTOMATIC rewrite rules
  ```

  And when an update occurs have your app read in the `.htaccess`, swap out the section between ##(++|--)AUTOMATIC rewrite rules, write it back to a temp file, then move the temp file to `.htaccess` (this makes the rewrtie-back atomic on *nix OSs).
- The second which might work if you know some regexp regular pattern which covers the rewrites (this is often the case) then use a rule to map them to a redirector script which looks up the new target and itself issues a:

  ```
  $server = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  header( "Location: http://$server/$newTarget?$parameters", TRUE, 301 );
  ```

  Note the 301 redirect -- this means that client browsers should cache this  and remember this in future.